# Android VideoView does not accept RTSP URI

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, android-videoview

Long-time user, first time poster. So thanks already to everyone who has helped on here, directly or indirectly before.

I'm having issues trying to stream an mp4/3gp video file which is being served over RTSP. The code for my POC is below, but is pretty much identical to the example I found here:

http://android-coding.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html

```
String rtspLink = "rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vid_view_rtsp);
    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(rtspLink));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.start();
}
```

Unfortunately, most of the examples I found are from a few years ago, this one in particular being from 2011. I am testing on a physical Samsung S3 (Android 4.3).
I have confirmed that the 3gp file does exist, and have successfully streamed it using VLC. I have the same issue with my own MP4's.

The stack trace/logcat generated is as follows:

```
09-15 02:16:07.520  25040-25040/org.chutchut.videoviewrtsp D/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource IOException happend :
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:761)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:665)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:960)
            at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:264)
            at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:52)
            at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:522)
            <.. snip ..>
09-15 02:16:07.520  25040-25040/org.chutchut.videoviewrtsp D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
09-15 02:16:07.530  25040-25040/org.chutchut.videoviewrtsp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Unable to to create media player
09-15 02:16:07.535  25040-25040/org.chutchut.videoviewrtsp W/VideoView﹕ Unable to open content: rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp
    java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1185)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1130)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:989)
            at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:264)
            at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:52)
            at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:522)
            <.. snip ..>
09-15 02:16:07.535  25040-25040/org.chutchut.videoviewrtsp D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned it... You do have the INTERNET permission, right?

Comment: Hey Juan, yes I have the relevant INTERNET permission in my manifest file.